# clunking noise over bumps from rear right 1997 ford ranger 3.0 liter 5 speed manual transmission

Tags: noise, drivetrain, ranger

I've noticed a clunking sound coming from rear right side of my truck when going over bumps. It's a 1997 Ford Ranger 3.0 liter manual 5 speed, has over 150,000 miles.  Haven't found loose suspension, leaf springs and shocks are fine. No noise when Jouncing the bed, but it does make the noise when pushing side to side on the bed.  Thoughts on what's causing it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It doesn't sound good whatever it is...

Comment: Frankly, this could be many things; bad shocks, worn bushings, worn axle bearings, worn rear end components, loose gas tank, loose spare tire, etc. You are going to need to isolate the sound better before we can help you.

Comment: If you can get a helper to reproduce the noise by shaking the truck, climb under it and start grabbing components with your hand. You should be able to isolate the problem.